# Error: a segue must either have a performhandler or it must override -perform swift

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

1. I am using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for a side menu.
   In this side menu, there is a tableview and in `didSelectRowAt` function of this table, the code is like this:

MenuViewController.swift:

```
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue", sender: self)

    case 1:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "OtherSegue", sender: self)

    defualt:
        break
    }
```

2. The segue from **MenuViewController** to another a **destinationViewController** has been set and its identifier is also set to "**MySegue**".
3. **IMPORTANT**: The **destinationViweController** is a **TabBarViewController**.

**PROBLEM:** when first row in tableView tapped, project crashes and the Error is:

```
Could not perform segue with identifier 'MySegue'. A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.
```